# Where does the term "arm's-length recursion" come from?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

I've recently seen the term "arm's-length recursion" for a recursive method with a check that short-circuits the method's true or intended base case. What's the origin of this term? How did it get this name?

Comment: Not an answer, only an explanation what it is: https://www.quora.com/What-is-arms-length-recursion